# Vba Code select value from dropdown List fill some cells in colour

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA and a bit struggling with it.
I am creating a report. In the report I have drop down list with a Flowers, let’s say Lilly, Rose Etc.  So when I select Rose I want some certain cells gets colour. I don’t want use conditional formatting as I need keep spreadsheet as low size as possible.
So far I got

```
Private Sub workbook_sheetchange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Targer As Rang
Select Case Range("B2")

Case " Rose"

Application.Goto Reference:="Header"
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0

End With

Application.Goto Reference:="Row"
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0

End With

Application.Goto Reference:="Fill"

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0

End With
End Select
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be after this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if "changed" cell is not "B2"

    With Sh '<--| reference sheet with "changed" cell
        Select Case .Range("B2").Value '<--| act with respect to B2 cell current value
            Case "Rose"
                With .Range("Header").Interior '<--| reference the specific named range instead of using 'Application.GoTo' method and 'Selection' object
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With .Range("Row").Interior '<--| reference the specific named range instead of using 'Application.GoTo' method and 'Selection' object
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                With .Range("Fill").Interior '<--| reference the specific named range instead of using 'Application.GoTo' method and 'Selection' object
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

which could be more effectively refactored to:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub workbook_sheetchange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if "changed" cell is not "B2"

    With Sh '<--| reference sheet with "changed" cell
        Select Case .Range("B2") '<--| act with respect to B2 cell current value
            Case "Rose"
                FormatCell Union(.Range("Header"), .Range("Row"), .Range("Fill")), _
                           xlSolid, _
                           xlAutomatic, _
                           xlThemeColorAccent6, _
                           -0.249977111117893, _
                           0 '<--| reference all listed named ranges and format their 'Interior' object with passed properties
                .Range("Fill").Interior.TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105 '<--| change only "Fill" named range 'Interior' 'TintAndShade' property
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub FormatCell(cell As Range, pttrn As XlPattern, pttrnClrIndx As XlColorIndex, thmClr As XlThemeColor, tntAndShd As Single, pttrnTntAndShd As Variant)
    With cell.Interior
        .pattern = pttrn
        .PatternColorIndex = pttrnClrIndx
        .ThemeColor = thmClr
        .TintAndShade = tntAndShd
        .PatternTintAndShade = pttrnTntAndShd
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then please mark it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this, the code works well. I would like to "accept" your answer but I am not sure how to do that (I cannot see any link)? Would help me out on this as well?

Comment: Hi,    Is there any way i can capture case  function?                                                  " Select Case str_type
    Case Is = ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Row")
        iColOffset = 1"   thank you

Comment: Do you mean :  Select Case UCase(.Range("B2")) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concerned about file size? I have created a workbook that does exactly as you require using conditional formatting and and the file size is 10.5Kb!!!

If you REALLY want to do this in VBA:

1 - Detect if B2 has changed by using the worksheet change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2"), Range(Target.Address)) Is 
            MsgBox "Cell B2 has been changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

2 - Test each cell in your data against your dropdown box. I have assumed your data is in range A1 to A10 for this example.

```
For Row = 1 To 10
    If Range("A" & Row).Value = Range("B2").Value Then
        'Colour your cell
    Else
        'Clear the colour from your cell
    End If
Next Row
```

Hopefully the above gives you a start.

Comment: The workbook will contain off large data,  therefore i don't want is is slowed down. Thank you for the code.